# meaning of 'take no thought' in the Gospel?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following extract, I'm not sure about the meaning of '**take no thought, saying**':

> Take no thought, saying, What shall we eat? or What shall we drink? or, Wherewithal shall we be clothed?

If '**take no thought**' means *don't think about*, then what is the role of '**saying**' here?

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It means "Have no care; be carefree; do not say 'What shall we eat?...'".

Comment: No, @oerkelens, I do not think so. This is [KJV for Matt. 6.31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+6.31&version=KJV), where [the Greek](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+6.31&version=SBLGNT) says μὴ οὖν μεριμνήσητε λέγοντες: the subjunctive verb μεριμνήσητε (worry) shares its implicit subject (2nd person plural, the audience for the Sermon on the Mount) with the participle λέγοντες, saying. Lawrence is correct that *thought* as a noun is merely an artifact of translation, and not a qualified candidate for subject of the participle *saying.*

Comment: This is a prime example of the AV being an unsatisfactory version for all but scholars of old translation methods, and archaic and ancient languages. Modern Bible versions are almost always more helpful, and essentially usually more accurate. But this belongs on hermeneutics SE, not here.

Answer (score 2):

Compare it with a more contemporary translation:

> So do not worry, saying, ‘What shall we eat?’ or ‘What shall we drink?’ or ‘What shall we wear?’
>   - [NIV](http://biblehub.com/niv/matthew/6.htm)

The phrase *take no thought* means *do not worry*. The short questions that follow represent things that some might worry (and hence talk) about.

> In modern versions this Greek word is translated as “anxious” or “worried”.  It’s a compound word, the first element meaning “parts”, the second referring to remembrance / calling to mind.  So it’s the sense of a divided mind – many parts, having many thoughts.  Thus the KJV repeatedly translates this warning as “Take no thought.”
>   - [Glen, The King's English](http://kingsenglish.info/2011/07/31/take-no-thought/)